# How should backbone.js handle a GET request that returns no results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

I have a number of text input elements that when its values are changed, will trigger a fetch on `listingListView`'s collection `listingCollection`, which then updates `listingListView` with the new data via the function `listingListView.refreshList` as shown below. I am using PHP/Codeigniter to expose a RESTful API.

**Problem:** Everything works fine if there are results retrieved from the `fetch()`. However, when the filters results in no result being returned, how should the server side and the client side handle it? Currently Chrome's javascript console displays a `404` error and in the Network tab, the XHR request is highlighted in red. All I want to do in the event of zero results returned, is to blank the `listingListView` and show a message like *(No results returned)* and not throw any errors in the javascript console. Thanks!

**PHP Code**

```
function listings_get() {
    // Get filters
    $price_min = $this->get('price_min');

    $this->load->model('app_model');
    $results = $this->app_model->get_listings($price_min);

    if($results)
        $this->response($results);
    else 
        $this->response(NULL);
}
```

**JS Code**

```
window.ListingListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'table',

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('reset', this.refreshList, this);
        this.model.bind('add', function(listing) {
            $(this.el).append(new ListingListItemView({ model: listing }).render().el);
        }, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        _.each(this.model.models, function(listing) {
            $(this.el).append(new ListingListItemView({ model: listing }).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    },

    close: function() {
        $(this.el).unbind();
        $(this.el).empty();
    },

    refreshList: function() {
        $(this.el).empty();
        this.render();
    }
});
```

Comment: is listingCollection a collection? seems like your binding ListingListView to a model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone triggers an "error" event on "sync" errors. You can catch the 404 error by creating an error handler function in your view.

```
this.model.on('error',this.defaultErrorHandler,this);

defaultErrorHandler: function(model, error) {
        console.log('status', error.status);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the error event in backbone; though it would be better to change the REST response from the server.  On no result send back 200 ok with an empty JSON object.  Be sure to test for a null object from the server.

Answer (score 0):

True, simply set response to empty, and the status to 200:

```
$this->response(NULL, 200);
```